# Match 10 words before a certain word

Tags: regex

I would like to match 2 words before a given key word using regex, so if the input string is

```
good morning every body
```

the output should be

```
morning every body
```

I know \w matches any word but how would I construct my regex to do the following

```
\wbody
```

Comment: PS: `\w` matchs a single charachter. Any single charachter but a new line !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\S+` to match one or more non-space characters.

```
\S+\s+\S+\s+body
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jO6zT2/3)

or use `\w+` instead of `\S+` in the above. `\s+` matches one or more space characters.

Comment: what if i want to define an arbitrary number of words?
is it possible to say \s{3}?

Comment: for three `(?:\S+\s+){3}body`, to match two words, `(?:\S+\s+){2}body` . Just change the nu,ber present inside `{}`

Comment: and what if I want it to get the 3 words after body?

Comment: Im trying this but it fails to match 3 words before and 3 words after body:
good morning every body good morning every
(?:\S+\s+){3}body(?:\s+\S+){3}

Answer (score 1):

```
(\w+\W+){2}body
```

You can change the 2 with any other number. [Try it out](https://regex101.com/r/qA6cA4/1).

Comment: Im trying this but it fails to match 3 words before and 3 words after body:
good morning every body good morning every
(\w+\W+){2}body(\w+\W+){2}

Comment: The part after "body" should be reversed: `\W+\w+` because after the word "body" you expect a non-word character.